# How to "PUT" an ajax call with expressjs

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, express, put

I have a form that upon submission is processed for an AJAX call.
In `express.js` in order to use other HTTP verbs the form has to have
`<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">`

The AJAX call has `type: "PUT"` and when it is sent to the server side I keep getting a `404`, `Cannot PUT`.

Is there something else that the AJAX or the form needs to submit successfully for a `PUT` request?
Any suggestions?

**routes/index.js**

```
app.put('/:library/:book/:genre/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.genre);
  res.send(200, {"youKnow":"putter"});  
});
```

**libraryBookForm.jade**

```
form#create-library-form(action='#', method='post')
      input(name="_method", value="PUT", type="hidden")
      div
        label Book
        input#book-name(type='text', name='book-name', required='required')
      div
        label Gender
        select#book-genre(name='book-genre')
          option(value='scifi') SciFi
          option(value='fantasy') Fantasy
      div
        input(type='submit', id='create-book-submit', value='Create Book')
```

**libraryBookAjax.js**

```
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/publicLibrary/drawingBook/fantasy'
      type: 'PUT',
      contentType: 'application/json: charset=utf-8',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: form.serialize()
    }).done(function(msg) {
      alert("put success: " + msg);
    }).fail(function(msg) {
      console.log("failure: " + msg);
    });
```

I've also tried `type: "POST"` in the AJAX request.  In that case, a `POST` request is sent and executed in the **routes** and not a `app.put`.

Comment: Does the trailing slash matter? I.e. should it not be `app.put('/:library/:book/:genre', function(req, res) {` instead?

Comment: OMG! yes... that's what happens when you don't sleep!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
app.put('/:library/:book/:genre/', function(req, res) {
```

to:

```
app.put('/:library/:book/:genre', function(req, res) {
```

The trailing slash is causing the 404 error, as there is none in the URL of your AJAX call.